# How to upload image file in MERN Stack Application with Multer

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, multer, mern

I'm trying to upload images as files using multer in my project, but I don't know why onCreate request in backend in the console I see on req.files: []; (empty array).

Here is where I create an element:

```
    const [imagesColors, setImagesColors] = useState([{image: [], color: ''}])
    
    const createProduct = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault ();
    
        const data = new FormData()
    
    data.append("name", name)
        data.append("description", description)
        data.append("processor", processor)
        data.append("ram", ram)
        data.append("storage", storage)
        data.append("imagesColors", imagesColors)
        data.append("price", price)
        data.append("type", type)
    
        console.log(data)
    
        fetch ('http://localhost:5000/products/create', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data
        })...
    
    const handleInputChangeColor = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const list = [...imagesColors];
        list[index][name] = value;
        setImagesColors(list);
      };
    
      const handleInputChangeImage = (e, index) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const file = e.target.files;
        const list = [...imagesColors];
        list[index][name] = file;
        setImagesColors(list);
      };
    
return (
...
    {imagesColors.map((x, i) => {
                        return (
                          <div className="box">
                            <label htmlFor="file" className="file--Input--Container">
                              <input
                                type="file"
                                id="file"
                                multiple
                                name="image"
                                className="file--Input"
                                filename="imageFile"
                                placeholder="Product Image"
                                onChange={e => handleInputChangeImage(e, i)}
                              />
                              <div className="file--Label--Container">
                                 <FaCloudUploadAlt className="upload--Icon"/> Upload Images
                              </div>
                            </label>
                            <select
                              onChange={e => handleInputChangeColor(e, i)}
                              value={x.color}
                              name="color"
                              defaultValue=""
                            >
                              <option selected value="">Color</option>
                              <option value='#4f5b66'>Space-gray</option>
                              <option value='#a7adba'>Silver</option>
                              <option value='#FFFFFF'>White</option>
                              <option value='#F63204'>Red</option>
                              <option value='#000000'>Black</option>
                              <option value='#0095CB'>Pacific-Blue</option>
                            </select>
                            <div className="btn-box">
                              {imagesColors.length !== 1 && <button onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>Remove</button>}
                              {imagesColors.length - 1 === i && <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        );
                      })}
```

When I console.log the state `imagesColors` it returns:

[image]

Here is the create function with multer function in backend:

```
const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, "../../shpJS/frontend/src/styles/images")
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, file.name)
    }
})

const uploads = multer({storage: imageStorage})

router.post('/create', uploads.array("imagesColors"), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req, ' asd')
    try {
        const data = {
            name: req.body.name,
            description: req.body.description,
            processor: req.body.processor,
            ram: req.body.ram,
            storage: req.body.storage,
            imagesColors: req.files,
            price: req.body.price,
            type: req.body.type,
            likes: req.body.likes
        }
        let product = await productService.create(data)
        res.status(201).json(product)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: error})
    }
})
```

And the result in console from request:

[image]

Comment: just see what does req.imagesColors log.

Comment: @NithinKJoy [object Object]. But how can I fix it ?

Comment: I have faced the same problem 2 days back while uploading(files and json data together) with multer. So what I did is converted images to base64 in the frontend and uploaded it and in the backend I converted base 64 into files. Do you need that source code?

Comment: @NithinKJoy Yes, can you provide it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send multiple files in the frontend using FormData API, you have to append those files one by one. You can append them to the same field, and that field will arrive as an array in the backend. If you want to send additional data along with each file, append that data to a *different* field in the same order.

In your case, it looks like this:

```js
for (const imageAndColor of imagesColors) {
  data.append('images', imageAndColor.image);
  data.append('colors', imageAndColor.color);
}
```

And in the backend change `uploads.array("imagesColors")` to `uploads.array("images")`. Your images will be in `req.files` and the colors in `req.body.colors`. The orders of both arrays are guaranteed — the first image is the first element in both arrays, second image is second element and so on.

Comment: Thanks man. That was what I'm looking for. Almost, but I think this order is going to help me a lot in frontend

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `imageColors` as an array of object(not array of files) which includes an image file list and color. Also you need to add brackets at end of form data key otherwise it will not parsed correctly.

You can map imageColors object before sending:

```js
data.append("imagesColors[]", imagesColors.map(i) => i.images[0])
```

And if you want to send color names too, you have to send them in another array:

```js
data.append("colors[]", imagesColors.map(i) => i.color)
```

Comment: so there is no way to send them in combined object ?

Comment: Maybe you get the idea why I'm trying to make it in combined object? So I can make a variants in frontend after that.

Comment: actually you can change filename with color before appending them. `imagesColors.forEach(i => data.append("imagesColors[]", i.images[0], i.color)`. Last `i.color` parameter will replace filename.

Comment: I'm getting Multer Error:
`MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (\multer\index.js:40:19)`

Comment: change `uploads.array("imagesColors")` with `uploads.any()`.

Comment: @NisanCoskun That's a bad way to solve the problem since that endpoint will accept any amount of files and the server is more susceptible to DDoS attacks. @Yollo to fix the error, use `data.append("imagesColors", ..)` because you're configuring multer with `uploads.array("imagesColors")`, not `uploads.array("imagesColors[]")`

Comment: this is almost the solution, but the only problem is that we change the originalname and the file we create in the destination is not the image.png it's just #EEEEEE (for exp)

Answer (score 0):

As the person who asked this question accepting any method to solve the problem (see comments of this question). I am answering with a method that doesn't use any package like multer to upload files.

So the method is first convert images to base64 in the frontend and send it to backend and in the backend convert base 64 back to files.

Below is frontend code for converting files to base64.

passed parameter `images` is nothing but `event.target.files`

```
const [imagesArray,setImagesArray]=useState()

let imageToBase64=(images)=>{  //passed parameter images here
    let imagesBase64=[]
    for(let image of images){
      const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      if (reader.readyState === 2) {
        let imageBase64=reader.result
        imagesBase64.push(imageBase64)
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
  setImagesArray(imagesBase64);
  }
```

set the frontend to send data in the below format

```
{
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    processor: req.body.processor,
    ram: req.body.ram,
    storage: req.body.storage,
    imagesColors: [base64 string,base64 string],//differnce here
    price: req.body.price,
    type: req.body.type,
    likes: req.body.likes
}
```

backend code

convert base64 to file (I believe you are uploading images so I used sharp package)

put this line in root file(probably index.js or app.js)
`app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}))`

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
const FileType = require("file-type");


router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    
 async function convert(base64) {
  var buffer = Buffer.from(base64.split(";base64,").pop(), "base64");
  let {ext} = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
  let newPath =
    `/public/any path/` +
    Date.now() +
    Math.random().toString().slice(2, 14) +
    "." +
    ext;

  await sharp(buffer)
    .resize(1920, 1080)
    .toFile(newPath)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

   return "done"
};

//this converts all base64 to images.
//warning: never `console.log(req.body.imagesColors)` because base64 is very very long string and logging that can crash your terminal.

if (req.body.imagesColors.length > 0)
    for (let image of req.body.imagesColors)
      await convert(image)
})
```